# No projects found while importing project from GIT

Tags: java, github

i am facing problem in importing project from github i.e,remote repository.it is giving no project found.and found the reason i should push .project and .classpath files also then only it will recognise the java project.but how to push them.
and i have 1more question

can i push more than 1 project into the remote repository.

i used following commands to push into the repository

```
git add .
git commit -m "intial commit"
git remote add swathi "https://github.com/swathiananthula/samplerepo.git"
git push swathi master
```

can anyone help me?
how can I import the project successfully into STS.

Comment: What is "it"? What is STS?

Comment: what about git init ? try running gitk and git-cola and check which files are commited. You should also pull from the remote after adding it.

Comment: Instead of eclipse we are using STS(Spring Tool Source)

Comment: ya sry forget to  mention it..i done it before git add .

Comment: only the .java files are committed.Other files like .classpath and .project are not getting commited.how to do that?

Comment: check your .gitignore file to see if there are any rules that ignore .project and .settings

Comment: @ gregory...ya pull is working..

Comment: @harun how to check .gitignore file.can u please explain me?

Comment: #################
## Eclipse
#################

*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

Comment: my .gitignore file is looking as above.so do i need to remove .classpath and ,project from there?

Comment: yes, remove them, then do git add and git push

Comment: @harun Thank you alot..ur hint worked for me..i did changes in .gitignore..so now it is working successfully..

Comment: @swathi great, could you consider marking my answer as selected then, so that people know that it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.project` and `.settings` entries (or any project config) from the .gitignore file and use `git add .` and `git push`. 
The next time someone clones your repository they would be able to import it as a project.

Just note that though if you check in project files, make sure you don't have machine specific entries in your project settings as it will differ for each developer. This includes any classpath entries with full paths etc.

For your initial question; yes you can have multiple projects in one repository, though many would not recommend it.

Comment: ya..now i came to know y shouldn't i keep more than 1 project in 1 repository.because while doing checkout for the other project we need to delete the default file created by git..at that time we must delete the project of the first checkout..